# Why has USBSerialDriverKit disappeared?

Tags: macos, xcode11, macos-catalina

At WWDC 2019, Apple announced a new driver architecture. More and more types of drivers are supposed to run in userspace instead of in the kernel. Among the first affected drivers types – according to the announcement – are USB-to-serial drivers.

This type of drivers is supposed to be implemented using the `USBSerialDriverKit`, and Apple published early documentation for it. However, the pages have disappeared. There are still indexed in Google, e.g.:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usbserialdriverkit. But they all lead to a 404. Related driver kits, e.g. [USBDriverKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usbdriverkit), are still online.

Why have the documentation and most likely also the related APIs disappeared – both from the web site as well as from macOS Catalina beta 3? Will they still be part of the final macOS Catalina?

Answer (score 0):

No reason was ever given why it disappeared. I guess it just wasn't ready yet.

Anyhow, it has reappeared with macOS Catalina 10.15.4 or 10.15.5.

I'm not sure how relevant it is for third parties. There is a limited number of USB-to-Serial chips available and many are already covered:

- **USB CDC ACM**: The official USB standard for USB-to-serial communication. Driver provided by Apple out of the box. If you have any control over the hardware, this should be your **preferred solution** as it works on all modern operating systems without further driver installation. This is the protocol usually implemented when the USB-to-serial conversion is implemented in software (in a MCU with a USB peripheral).
- **FTDI chips** (such as FT232x, FT2232, FT4232): Popular chip for USB-to-serial conversion. Chinese clones exist as well. Driver is provided by Apple out-of-the-box.
- **Silicon Labs CP210x chips**: Popular chip for USB-to-serial conversion. Driver is provided by Apple out-of-the-box.
- **WCH CH34xx chips**: Popular chip for USB-to-serial conversion from the Chinese manufacturer WCH. Driver is provided by Apple out-of-the-box.
- **Prolific PL230x chips**: Chips for USB-to-serial conversion from a Taiwanese manufacturer. No user-space driver available yet.

So the *Prolific* driver is the only one missing. With the up-coming Apple Silicon based Macs, they will probably have pressure to deliver it by the end of 2020. Looking forward to it.